# Colab tab keeps crashing because It runs out of memory but I am not out of memory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

It tends to happen when I am rendering out picture that are at or above 1080p they keep popping up in the tab but then stop and after 15-30 minutes the tab looks like this.
[memory error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aVmQ.jpg)